# mkdir: cannot create directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mkdir

Hello I have the following bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( "$@" )


echo "${arr[1]}"
echo "${arr[3]}"
echo "${arr[2]}"

mkdir "${arr[1]}/segments"

echo `pwd`
cd "${arr[1]}/segments"

mkdir "${arr[1]}/segments/${arr[3]}/segment_${arr[2]}"
cd "${arr[3]}/segment_${arr[2]}"

echo `pwd`

read -p "aa: " cuvant
```

The echos are for me to understand what exactly is going on. I spitted the "mkdir" command in order to see if it is creating a folder or not. The outcome of the script is:

[image]

As you can see is not creating the other folder underneath the streams folder.

I have also a similar code that is actually doing the work:

```
mkdir "${arr[1]}_720_directory"
                ffmpeg -i ${arr[1]} -vf scale=1280:720 -preset slow -crf 18 "${arr[1]}_720_directory/output.mp4"
                arr1=("${arr[1]}_720_directory/output.mp4" "$resolution" )
                bash "$path"/check_resolution_video.sh "${arr1[@]}"
                bash "$path"/bitrate.sh "${arr[1]}_720_directory" "output.mp4" "${arr[0]}" "$path"
```

This code is calling another file which is creating different bit-rates and that file will call the script which is not working.

The result:

[image]

Here is the segments folder and the new folder that was created.

In this case I do not know what can be the actual error of the "mkdir" command. If you have any suggestion just let me know please.

Comment: If you're trying to create a directory *including its parent directories* (it's really hard to tell from your question tbh) then you need `mkdir -p`

Comment: Thank you ! I am trying this and I will be back. I am trying to create

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much! Is working!